# MDX Dynamic Date Filter

Tags: sass, powerbi, mdx

I am trying to import data into PowerBI via SSAS using an MDX statement.

The script below selects records where the week ending date = 16-Feb.

I need to modify this to return both week ending 16-Feb and 9-Feb.

I have used LASTCHILD.LAG(11) to return 16-Feb so need a way of returning the -11 and -12 member in my 'week' hierarchy.

Please help, thanks!

```
SELECT 
        {[Measures].[Roster Actual Sum Hours Nett]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        {
                [Staff].[Display Name].[Display Name].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Staff].[StaffNumber].[StaffNumber].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Staff].[CubeCode].[CubeCode].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Site].[Site Name].[Site Name].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Site].[GeographyName].[GeographyName].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Roster Type].[Roster Type].[Roster Type].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Date].[Roster Week].LASTCHILD.LAG(11)
        }
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
        MEMBER_CAPTION,
        MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
     ON ROWS
FROM 
[Model]
CELL PROPERTIES 
    VALUE,
    BACK_COLOR,
    FORE_COLOR,
    FORMATTED_VALUE,
    FORMAT_STRING,
    FONT_NAME,
    FONT_SIZE,
    FONT_FLAGS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

```
SELECT 
    {[Measures].[Roster Actual Sum Hours Nett]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
        {
                [Staff].[Display Name].[Display Name].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Staff].[StaffNumber].[StaffNumber].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Staff].[CubeCode].[CubeCode].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Site].[Site Name].[Site Name].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Site].[GeographyName].[GeographyName].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Roster Type].[Roster Type].[Roster Type].ALLMEMBERS*
                [Date].[Roster Week].[Roster Week].ALLMEMBERS
        }
     ON ROWS
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        {
            [Date].[Roster Week].LastChild.Lag(11),
            [Date].[Roster Week].LastChild.Lag(12)
        } ON COLUMNS
    FROM [Model]
)
```